# How to get the image if we have path in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tweepy

I have the path of images inside the pandas dataframe I need to get the images inside the dataframe if I have path of it is it possible inside the dataframe?
I need to store the images in the dataframe column along with their path.
**This is how I have tried it but its not working. Also the image size is small its 50x50**

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
image=df['profile']
def path_to_image_html(path):
    return '<img src="'+ path + '" style=height:50px;"/>'

a=HTML(df.to_html(escape=False ,formatters=dict(image=image)))
```

**These are the path of images inside the dataframe column**

```
http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/797804071063343105/KPytXWtY_normal.jpg
http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/903374198009188353/pDuYl5Uk_normal.jpg
http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1101088756432396290/5bzisDRx_normal.png
```

Comment: I think an image can be read into `numpy` not sure if that can then be read into the df.

Comment: @Sid can you make it with numpy?

Comment: why do the images need to be stored in the dataframe?

Comment: I need to know that which image belongs to which row that is why i am saving in the dataframe

Comment: @jeschwar you can make the answer if you some good approach to it